# Java Generics "upcast" to unparameterized type

Tags: java, generics, compilation, jvm, rtti

Why I get ClassCastException only when uncomment third statement in Main.main() ? And no exceptions, but well executed first and second statements?

```
public class Tuple<K, V> {
    public final K first;
    public final V second;

public Tuple(K first, V second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

@Override public String toString() {
    return "Tuple{" + "first = " + first + ", second = " + second + '}';
    }
}

class Test { static Tuple f(){return new Tuple("test", 8);} }

class Bar {}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tuple<String, Bar> t = Test.f();
        System.out.println(t);
      //System.out.println(t.second.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My understanding is that will not work in Java.  Your generics aren't being given a type, they're Generics.  This would work if you had something like `public final K<String> first;` and it would return String.

Comment: `Test.f()` returns a raw type. This error would be easier to catch if you avoided using raw types. The return type of `Test.f()` should be defined as `Tuple<String, Integer>` to match the value being returned. This will then cause a compile error on `Tuple<String, Bar> t = Test.f()`. Type safety is a powerful feature.

Comment: You should post the full error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to Bar` - now it's becoming much clearer...

Comment: Read [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a chain of method calls:

```
System.out.println(t.second.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

the compiler effectively expands this to:

```
TypeOfTSecond tmpTSecond = t.second;
Class<?> clazzTmp = tmp.getClass();
String nameTmp = clazzTmp.getSimpleName();
System.out.println(nameTmp);
```

Now, if it happens that `t.second` is a generic type, the compiler will insert a cast to the type that it things `t.second` will be:

```
Bar tmpTSecond = (Bar) t.second;
```

So even though you're never accessing any `Bar`-specific functionality, you will get the `ClassCastException`.

---

To demonstrate this, here is the bytecode:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2        // Method Test.f:()LTuple;
       3: astore_1
       4: getstatic     #3        // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: aload_1
       8: getfield      #4        // Field Tuple.second:Ljava/lang/Object;
      11: checkcast     #5        // class Bar
      14: invokevirtual #6        // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      17: invokevirtual #7        // Method java/lang/Class.getSimpleName:()Ljava/lang/String;
      20: invokevirtual #8        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      23: return
```

Line 8 is where `t.second` is pushed onto the stack; line 11 is where the cast to `Bar` occurs.

---

This only comes about because of the raw types used when declaring `test.f()`:

```
static Tuple f(){return new Tuple("test", 8);}
```

If this were correctly declared as

```
static Tuple<String, Integer> f(){return new Tuple<>("test", 8);}
```

then this line

```
Tuple<String, Bar> t = Test.f();
```

wouldn't compile. But the use of raw types disables the compiler's type checking, so runtime errors like this cannot be guaranteed to be prevented.

---

The main take-away lesson is [*never use raw types*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

The secondary lesson is pay attention to your compiler's (or IDE's) warnings. Compiling this code, I was told:

```
Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

and when I recompiled with that flag:

```
Main.java:19: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to Tuple(K,V) as a member of the raw type Tuple
      return new Tuple("test", 8);
             ^
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class Tuple
    V extends Object declared in class Tuple
Main.java:26: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
    Tuple<String, Bar> t = Test.f();
                                 ^
  required: Tuple<String,Bar>
  found:    Tuple
2 warnings
```

Comment: Note that the compiler is not *required* to insert a cast of `t.second` to `Bar` in this case. That is does so is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()), for `getClass()` method in `Object` class

The actual result type is **`Class<? extends |X|>`** where **|X|** is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

In the declaration part, the type is Bar

```
Tuple<String, Bar> t = Test1.f();
```

Since there is no parent-child relationship between `Integer` and `Bar`, while trying to cast Integer to Bar, you get a ClassCastException (i.e. `Integer extends Bar` is not correct)

Here is the fix

```
Tuple<String, Object> t = Test1.f();
```

**Note:** [It is not encouraged to use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). This answer just explains reason behind the failure and the fix for that.

Comment: Down vote is of no use, unless one the down voter clarifies what the problem is

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing it's because your fix is based on the usage of raw types. If `Test.f()` was declared with type arguments that matched the value being returned (`<String, Integer>`), you'd get a compile error for using `<String, Object>`. Although it works, it encourages bad design since it avoids the actual problem (lack of type safety) which is shown through the warning message you get from doing this. I personally wouldn't downvote for this reason (it still works), but some people are stricter than others.

Comment: I get it! So, here at SO, rather than just providing the fix and explaining the reason behind the fix, we also have to suggest best practices. Like you said, I have missed to say that usage of raw types is discouraged. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. I personally feel it didn't deserve a downvote cause it still works, but I probably would have upvoted if the answer encouraged better practices.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, I updated my answer with additional notes